# Why are the debug tool bar buttons in an Eclipse C/C++ debugging session disabled?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-source

I am debugging a C/C++ application from Android platform code using Eclipse. I am doing this using "Remote C/C++ Application" debug configuration.

I have gdbserver running on android device listening for connections.
I started native debug session from eclipse.
Eclipse attached to remote process. I added a breakpoint. When I did something that should hit this breakpoint, I did see eclipse stop at break point in android C++ library code. The step over etc buttons were all enabled. When I pressed next, all the buttons got disabled. Instead of stepping line by line, it is stopping at the next break point.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you debugging a multi-thread process? This might be the reason why you see this phenomenon.

The thread which has the first break point has yield and the kernel has been switched to execute another thread which has your second break point.

Comment: Yes. It is multi-thread process. How to make eclipse step debug line by line?